# where to place Redux private state which are not rendered in UI

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my app, some DOM value such as `getBoundingClientRect` is required to some reducer. I can get these data, but the problem is that where to place those. In redux, typically, the data should be kept in store. But I suppose the data in store should be related to `render` somehow rather than some data just for calculation.

Put it in a more general way, If I need to refer to something outside reducer? Is there a decent place they can live in context of redux

Comment: Is getBoundingClientRect part of the state of the app, or is it only ever used by one React component?

Comment: Image when you click a button, you need to place the item to a new @ 
@saille position based on current position, and the current position can be retrieved by `getBoundingClientRect`, I think it makes sense to treat 'click button' as an action. And I can get the value `getBoundingClientRect` from the DOM read by `ref` callback. Currently, I put the DOM in a separate object whose only purposes are set and get

Comment: @saille i.e. the DOM `set` by `ref` callback, and `get` when the 'click button' action is triggered.

Comment: @saille I think DOM properly can never changed by React, so there is no point to place them in Redux store. But we need them when reducing the action. What is the correct place for them?

Comment: @saille . Forget about DOM for a moment, I think there is always some kind of data in an application which can not be reduced and any change to them will not trigger any UI update. They can only be set and get to keep track of the application state somehow. What is the fair place they should stay under Redux logic